# Plugin Hook When New Author Added

Tags: plugins, hooks, user-roles

Is there a way to add a hook for a plugin when a new author is added by the administrator?

I would like to be able to add that user to my plugin database table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register).